# Why I cannot restore Apple TV from tvOS 10 preview?

Tags: itunes, restore, appletv

It just shows error "The Apple TV software update center could not be contacted. The requested resource was not found." Is there anything I can do to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug. Download the IPSW manually from [developer.apple.com/tvos/download](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/download/), alt-click the Restore button and select your IPSW.